# Kendo Grid Filter - Show Yes/No if column has information

Tags: kendo-grid

As the title says, on a specific column in a grid, I am trying to show Yes/No as filtering options, depending on whether the column has information.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can be done using filter menu customization. Please visit [here](http://jsbin.com/qehugexo/3/edit) for a working demo

More details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435857/kendo-ui-filter-on-boolean)